# AWS invoke a lambda function by another lambda function gives time out error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am new to AWS and doing some exercises on lambda functions. I want to call a lambda function by another lambda function but it gives an error.

Both functions are assigned same execution role (which has "AWSLambdaExecute",  AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole, AWSLambdaFullAccess policies assigned) and no vpc is assigned to any.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2017-11-13T09:19:08.103Z b19fcd35-c853-11e7-a038-79c5d04b5126 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}
```

Function invoking the "test" lambda function

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'EU(Ireland)';
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
 var params = {
    FunctionName: 'test', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
    InvocationType: 'Event',       
    Payload: '{ "name" : "Alex" }'
};

 lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log("ds");
  if (err) {
   context.fail(err);
  } 
  else {
   context.succeed('Lambda test said '+ data.Payload);
  }
 })
};
```

"test" function

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
console.log('Lambda test Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null,2));
context.succeed('Hello ' + event.name);
};
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrectly set the region.

```
AWS.config.region = 'EU(Ireland)';
```

should be

```
AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';
```